# in Django sql table with dots as a decimal separator but in the admin are displayed with commas

Tags: django, django-templates

I have this error in Django

```
error during template rendering .... argument must be int or float
```

I wonder if it's because in my sql table I have columns with coordinates that have dots as a separator but when I look at the display in the admin these coordinates are displayed with commas

my models :

```
class VilleStation(models.Model):
    nomVille = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    adresse = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    cp = models.CharField(max_length=5)
    latitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    longitude = models.DecimalField(max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.nomVille
```

in my settings

```
LANGUAGE_CODE = "fr-fr"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

DECIMAL_SEPARATOR = True
```

thank

Answer (score 0):

sorry for my mistake, it was an error in a field of the table. There's no more problem.